# MPEG-DASH - Dash is not valid! Error

Tags: video-streaming, mpeg-dash, mp4box, dash.js

I've been trying to learn MP4Box and Dash, which I'm making some progress, but I cannot seem to get my video to work. I followed the instructions on adding the player to a simple html page and I tested with it a known MPD from Dash's test pages and everything works perfect with the player, so I've narrowed it down the the MPD file.

I ran my MPD file through the Dash validator and it fails. I get the following error:

```
Start XLink resolving
=====================

XLink resolving successful



Start MPD validation
====================

Line:Col[5:20]:cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'MPD'.
MPD validation not successful - DASH is not valid!



BUILD FAILED
/var/www/html/conformance/current/webfe/mpdvalidator/build.xml:65: Java 
returned: 4

Total time: 53 seconds
```

I'm using MP4Box to segment the mp4, so it may be an incorrect command. I'm using and this is the command I'm using:

```
MP4Box -dash 4000 -frag 1000 -rap -segment-name segment_ rogue_one.mp4
```

I'm not sure what I'm looking for when I look at the MPD file, but I did look through it trying to see if I can find any noticeable errors, but it looks good to me. Here is my MPD file:

```
<MPD type="static" xmlns="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:full:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.5S" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H2M28.34S">
    <ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="http://gpac.sourceforge.net">
        <Title>Media Presentation Description for file rogue_one.mp4 generated with GPAC </Title>
    </ProgramInformation>
    <Period start="PT0S" duration="PT0H2M28.34S">
        <AdaptationSet>
            <ContentComponent id="1" contentType="video"/>
            <ContentComponent id="2" contentType="audio" lang="eng"/>
            <Representation id="1" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.640029,mp4a.40.02" width="1920" height="816" sampleRate="44100" numChannels="2" lang="eng" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="7969270">
                    <SegmentList timescale="1000" duration="10050">
                    <Initialization sourceURL="rogue_one_dash.mp4"/>
                    <SegmentURL media="segment_1.m4s"/>
                    ...
                    <SegmentURL media="segment_43.m4s"/>
                </SegmentList>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
    </Period>
</MPD>
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging into it more, ffmpeg was the issue. I changed the command on encoding and it started working. What's weird is, although it works, I still get an Dash is not valid! Error, not sure why.

Comment: Can you tell what was the issue and what was your resolution?